# Tutorials for Ruby on Rails 1.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently joined a web project which was started long time ago, so long ago it still uses the ancient Ruby 1.0.6 with Rails 1.2.3.

I need to learn Rails as I go, and I've been told that tutorials for the current version of Rails (5) won't be helpful at all because Rails has changed so much since version 1.

Where might I or anyone else who joins a long-running Rails project find some really old Rails tutorials to go with this really old version of Rails? Any tutorials would be great. I would ideally like something like the amazing [Rails Book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book).

Note: I did attempt to search for such tutorials on Google, with no luck. Filtering to results from before December 2007 (when Rails 2.0 came out) gave better results, but dead and updated links abound. I think it will be more time efficient to check if anyone just knows where to find one such tutorial, rather than me blindly clicking around for hours and hours. If I should also ask this question somewhere else, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

How complex is this application?

It would be best to upgrade to more current (and supported) versions of Ruby and Rails.

Using such an outdated stack is not a good idea for many reasons, one of the major ones is security.

Comment: I agree. Hopefully once I'm a more established member of the team I'll be able to convince them to upgrade. It's a large application so it would definitely take a while.